# How to upload file ,create new folder using ssh_connent function php?

Tags: file-upload

How to upload file, create new folder using `ssh_connent` function php.

get.php file uploaded http://xxxx.com/demo/review/

But the review folder doesn't exist on the xxxx.com. I want to create review folder then upload the get.php file.

Answer (score 0):

See ssh2_ftp function manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php

Comment: Already, I have use this link to develop file upload code. review folder doesn't exist on the xxxx.com